# Передача данных из C# приложения методом POST

Tags: c#

Задача сериализовать класс в json и передать его POST'ом на сервер.
Я написал код и он работает но у меня ощущение что я наделал много лишнего.
Подскажите хорошую практику для решения моей задачи.

```
//package - сериализуемый объект который надо передать
JsonPackage package = new JsonPackage( userData ); 
DataContractJsonSerializer jsonFormatter = new DataContractJsonSerializer( typeof( JsonPackage ) );

WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create( "http://localhost:52733/set" );
request.ContentType = "application/json";
request.Method = "POST";

MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

jsonFormatter.WriteObject( ms, package );

ms.Flush();
ms.Position = 0;

StreamReader sr = new StreamReader( ms );
string jsonString = sr.ReadToEnd();

StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter( request.GetRequestStream() );
sw.Write( jsonString );

sr.Dispose();
sw.Dispose();
ms.Dispose();
request.GetResponse();
```

Comment: Как-то с потоками вы переборщили, почему не писать сразу в нужный?

Comment: вместо ручного вызова Dispose, используйте оператор using: https://habrahabr.ru/post/129283/

Comment: Андрей NOP, вот я поэтому и задал свой вопрос))) как сделать правильно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не проверял, но думаю, что ваш код можно сократить до такого:

```
JsonPackage package = new JsonPackage(userData);
DataContractJsonSerializer jsonFormatter = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(JsonPackage));

WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:52733/set");
request.ContentType = "application/json";
request.Method = "POST";

using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
    jsonFormatter.WriteObject(stream, package);

request.GetResponse();
```

Нет нужды создавать кучу потоков, достаточно взять нужный и сериализовать сразу в него. Ну и, обратите внимание, лучше использовать конструкцию `using` - она вызывает `Dispose()` в блоке `finally`, т.е. поток будет освобожден даже при ошибке.

Comment: Отлично все работает спасибо!